# PHP variables not showing up. GETid not working properly

Tags: get

I have all the login scripts and profiles set up. I have a data table where all the profile information is stored called `plus_signup` but I can't seem to get this `GET[id]` thing to work. Am I missing something? Here's what I have. 
When I view the page with the code I have now, there are blank areas where PHP is supposed to fill in the variables.

```
session_start();

include "include/z_db.php";

if ($_GET['id']){

$id = $_GET['id'];

} else if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

}
else {
print "important data to render this page is missing";
exit();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plus_signup WHERE id='$userid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$userid = $row["userid"];
$name = $row["name"];
$location = $row["location"];
$sex = $row["sex"];
$aboutme = $row["aboutme"];

}

$check_pic = "users/$id/image01.jpg";
$default_pic = "users/0/image01.jpg";
if (file_exists($check_pic)){
$user_pic = "<img src=\"$check_pic\" width=\"175px\"/>";
} else {
$user_pic = "<img src=\"$default_pic\"/>";
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little late and that you may have already figured out the answer to this question, but I was having the same issue and just figured it out.

Your SQL query is calling on a variable that has not been defined.

```
session_start();

include "include/z_db.php";

if ($_GET['id']){

$id = $_GET['id'];

} else if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

}
else {
print "important data to render this page is missing";
exit();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plus_signup WHERE id='$userid'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$userid = $row["userid"];
$name = $row["name"];
$location = $row["location"];
$sex = $row["sex"];
$aboutme = $row["aboutme"];

}

$check_pic = "users/$id/image01.jpg";
$default_pic = "users/0/image01.jpg";
if (file_exists($check_pic)){
$user_pic = "<img src=\"$check_pic\" width=\"175px\"/>";
} else {
$user_pic = "<img src=\"$default_pic\"/>";
}}
```

You are getting the 'id' from the url and storing it as $id. When you call your query, you are having it search for where ID = $userid when you really should be having it search for ID = $id.

**Make sure that your variables are the same throughout!**

^Hope that helps some people avoid an hour or two of frustration when trying to figure out why their function isn't working!